# .DS_Store' does not appear to be a valid migration

Tags: sql, clojure, luminus

Has anyone run across this error when running a migration using luminus?

```
CREATE TABLE users
(
    id VARCHAR(20) PRIMARY KEY,
    first_name VARCHAR(30),
    last_name VARCHAR(30),
    email VARCHAR(30),
    admin BOOLEAN,
    last_login TIME,
    is_active BOOLEAN,
    pass VARCHAR(100)
);

CREATE TABLE goals
(
    id VARCHAR(20) PRIMARY KEY,
    goal VARCHAR(254),
    goal_description VARCHAR(max),
    last_entry TIME,
    is_complete BOOLEAN
);
```

Comment: `.DS_STORE` is a Macintosh desktop file.  And this question is confusing because you mention `.DS_STORE` in the title and then never mention it again.

Comment: Sorry about that, but yes. I'm not sure why it would even attempt to read .DS_STORE. I ran a migration successfully though after adding another table it started to throw that error my way. 
It makes absolutely no sense to me.

Answer (score 1):

Issue resolved. I manually created my migration files opposed to running 'lein migratus create add-goals table'.